# QT debugging not resolving pointers

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, pointers, qt-creator

Not sure if this is a bug, or meant to be. Googling this did not give any information except [QT-Creator Troubleshoot](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-troubleshooting-debugging.html) with heading:

> Pointer Variable Members Are Not Displayed Directly

*Simply refering to: enable dereferncing of pointers.*

I have this enabled, please see screenshot of debugging session

**Problem:**

Just as creating a new object e.g.:

```
QString newString = QString("This is a new string");
```

is shown in the debugger and the contents of `newString` is shown in the debugger.

However changing this to a pointer e.g.

```
QString *newString = new QString("This is a new string");
```

Just as all my defined pointers in the screenshot, these pointers and `newString` pointer will not resolve the contents held.

**Is this a bug or is QT unable to resolve this?**

see below indepth view of debugger info:

**debugger info screenshot**

[image: Debug Screenshot]

**debugger info data**

```
Locals      
    appdata @0x7fffffffe000 QString
        d   @0x5555557ea610 QString::Data
            [QArrayData]    @0x5555557ea610 QArrayData
                alloc   20  uint
                capacityReserved    0   uint
                offset  24  qptrdiff
                ref @0x5555557ea610 QtPrivate::RefCount
                shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                size    21845   int
        null    @0x7ffff6a8d6a0 QString::Null
    dir @0x7fffffffe060 QDir
        d_ptr   @0x7fffffffe060 QSharedDataPointer<QDirPrivate>
            d   @0x5555557ede00 QDirPrivate
    projDir @0x7fffffffe010 QString
        d   @0x5555557eabf0 QString::Data
            [QArrayData]    @0x5555557eabf0 QArrayData
                alloc   11  uint
                capacityReserved    0   uint
                offset  24  qptrdiff
                ref @0x5555557eabf0 QtPrivate::RefCount
                shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                size    21845   int
        null    @0x7ffff6a8d6a0 QString::Null
    this    @0x5555557e8c80 dataManager
        configFile  0x0 QFile *
        configPath  0x0 QString *
        networkManager  @0x5555557e8c80 netman
        paths_list  @0x5555557e8d00 QStringList
        userFile    @0x5555557eea70 QFile
        userName    @0x5555557e8cf8 QString
            d   @0x5555557efb30 QString::Data
                [QArrayData]    @0x5555557efb30 QArrayData
                    alloc   3   uint
                    capacityReserved    0   uint
                    offset  24  qptrdiff
                    ref @0x5555557efb30 QtPrivate::RefCount
                    shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                        [0] @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData
                        [1] @0x7ffff6a16ef8 QArrayData
                    size    2   int
            null    @0x7ffff6a8d6a0 QString::Null
        userPath    @0x5555557ec8f0 QString
            d   @0x5555557ed6b0 QString::Data
            null    @0x7ffff6a8d6a0 QString::Null
    userConfName    @0x7fffffffdff0 QString
        d   @0x5555557df5e0 QString::Data
            [QArrayData]    @0x5555557df5e0 QArrayData
                alloc   14  uint
                capacityReserved    0   uint
                offset  24  qptrdiff
                ref @0x5555557df5e0 QtPrivate::RefCount
                shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                    [0] @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData
                        alloc   0   uint
                        capacityReserved    0   uint
                        offset  24  qptrdiff
                        ref @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QtPrivate::RefCount
                        shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                            [0] @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData
                                alloc   0   uint
                                capacityReserved    0   uint
                                offset  24  qptrdiff
                                ref @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QtPrivate::RefCount
                                shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                                size    0   int
                            [1] @0x7ffff6a16ef8 QArrayData
                                alloc   0   uint
                                capacityReserved    0   uint
                                offset  0   qptrdiff
                                ref @0x7ffff6a16ef8 QtPrivate::RefCount
                                shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                                size    0   int
                        size    0   int
                    [1] @0x7ffff6a16ef8 QArrayData
                        alloc   0   uint
                        capacityReserved    0   uint
                        offset  0   qptrdiff
                        ref @0x7ffff6a16ef8 QtPrivate::RefCount
                        shared_null @0x7ffff6a16ee0 QArrayData [2]
                        size    0   int
                size    21845   int
        null    @0x7ffff6a8d6a0 QString::Null
Inspector       
Expressions     
Return Value        
Tooltip
```

Comment: Is this a debug or release build?

Comment: @MrEricSir debug session, still in dev phase (alpha). but I am confused as to how it really makes a difference to which build it is?

Comment: Well, as far as I can see the QT Creator uses a system debugger (e.g. GDB), which normally needs debug information included in the executable to display it (which is normally not present in the release builds).

Comment: First and foremost, which Qt Creator version, under which OS and using which debugger?

Comment: (Second: we *do* help on IRC, you were just unlucky, try during CET working hours. Third: for the love of kittens, use QSettings or QStandardPaths rather than assembling those paths manually!)